# Chromecast: maximize tab on TV while multitasking on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, television

I'm trying to use Chromecast to watch an ESPN3 game in full-screen on my TV, while continuing to work in Chrome on my laptop (OS: Mavericks). The ESPN3 player doesn't have an option to stream directly through Chromecast (to my knowledge), so I've been casting the entire tab. This works fine, I can see the tab on my TV. If I want to view full-screen, I can maximize the viewer. This maximizes the viewer on the TV, and also my laptop screen. So far, so good.

The problem is, I want to keep using my laptop for other stuff. If I want a different application, I can cmd-tab to Finder, then right-click the Chrome icon and hide it, allowing me to see other stuff on my screen. However, if I want to use Chrome, as soon as I activate any Chrome window, the video pops up as full-screen an obscures my view.

I suppose I could use a different browser for internet stuff, but that's obnoxious! For example, I'm using Chrome's dev tools pane to debug a page I'm working on. I don't want to give up using Chrome for other purposes just because I'm watching something on TV.

How can I go about watching a full-screen tab on TV, while still being able to use Chrome for other purposes on my computer?

---

Update: I tried having the media window in a separate `space`, but when I go fullscreen it always takes up the laptop screen no matter which `space` I switch to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new space, opening a new Chrome window in that space, opening ESPN in that new window, and cast that single tab on that isolated Chrome window to your TV? Then you should be able to work in your other space(s) and leave that one alone/aside to stream to your TV.

I do something similar when I want to work in Chrome but stream Hulu/Netflix/whatever to my TV via AirPlay (I set the AirPlay display as a separate display and drag over a totally separate Chrome window to that AirPlay display).

Comment: I tried this, but when I switch spaces, the full-screen viewer switches too and always takes up the screen of my laptop. I can't seem to get it to stay in the other space.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome Extension [Fullscreen Anything](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fullscreen-anything/olcfgpmjldkkjdclidhcbonieibfhhdh/) should allow you to do this.

Answer (score -1):

With Chrome 35, Fullscreen stays within the tab, which should directly solve your problem.